# Storing only part of output into shell variable

Tags: linux, bash, sh

hi i am using a bash script.
 here i execute this code.

```
/usr/bin/mxci <<EOF
SELECT substring(substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))),
(1+locate('.',substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))))),15 ) as TAB_NAME
FROM table(explain('/home/vivek/MFCABS1031VCAT.VSCH.A9B69395AE3238A4184A90CD1F28C161', '%'))
WHERE OPERATOR LIKE '%FILE_SCAN%';
EOF'
```

This will return a output as

```
>>SELECT substring(substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))),
+>(1+locate('.',substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))))),15 ) as TAB_NAME
+>FROM table(explain('/home/vivek/MFCABS1031VCAT.VSCH.A9B69395AE3238A4184A90CD1F28C161', '%'))
+>WHERE OPERATOR LIKE '%FILE_SCAN%';

TAB_NAME
---------------

TEST1

--- 1 row(s) selected.
>>exit;
```

Now i know how to store this entire output into a single variable and print it But i am not able to figure out how to store partial information into variable.
Like if i want to store only TEST1 into the variable, what should i do.

Thanks in advance

The output of the varaible Test

```
/home/vivek: echo "$test"
Hewlett Packard Enterprise NonStop(TM) SQL/MX Conversational Interface 3.7
(c) Copyright 2003-2019 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP.
>>SELECT substring(substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))),
+>(1+locate('.',substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))))),15 ) as TAB_NAME
+>FROM table(explain('/home/vivek/MFCABS1031VCAT.VSCH.A9B69395AE3238A4184A90CD1F28C161', '%'))
+>WHERE OPERATOR LIKE '%FILE_SCAN%';

TAB_NAME
---------------

TEST1

--- 1 row(s) selected.
>>exit;

End of MXCI Session
/home/vivek:
```

Comment: Does `mxci` provide any options to avoid outputting the human-friendly (but irrelevant to a machine) table?

Comment: Maybe `echo "$TEST" | sed -ne '/^---/,/^---/p'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe your output to this awk:

```
your_cmd | awk '/^TAB_NAME$/{n=NR} n && NR==n+3{print; exit}'
```

```
TEST1
```

This `awk` looks for a line that is equal to `TAB_NAMES` and stores that line no. Following which it prints a line whose line no is `stored no + 3`.

To store this shown value in a variable use:

```
myvar=$(your_cmd | awk '/^TAB_NAME$/{n=NR} n && NR==n+3{print; exit}')
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I tried as you suggested,but it did not work.
i stored the value in $test and than did the pipe thing like this.

/home/vivek: echo "$test" |awk '/^TAB_NAME$/{n=NR} n && NR==n+3{print; exit}'
/home/vivek:

Comment: /home/vivek: echo "$test"
Hewlett Packard Enterprise NonStop(TM) SQL/MX Conversational Interface 3.7
(c) Copyright 2003-2019 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP.
>>SELECT substring(substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))),
+>(1+locate('.',substring(tname from (1+locate('.',tname))))),15 ) as TAB_NAME
+>FROM table(explain('/home/vivek/MFCABS1031VCAT.VSCH.A9B69395AE3238A4184A90CD1F28C161', '%'))
+>WHERE OPERATOR LIKE '%FILE_SCAN%';

TAB_NAME
---------------

TEST1

--- 1 row(s) selected.
>>exit;

End of MXCI Session
/home/vivek:

Comment: I ran this `awk` command on your input and got `TEST1` in output. You can see it working here: https://ideone.com/NVSJOH